# How did this person become a metahuman?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

The metahuman Cisco nicknamed DeathBolt wasn't in Central City when the Accelerator went boom- so how did he mutate/gain his powers? Was this ever explained?

Comment: "*The source of his mutation is unclear, as Simmons was known to have not been in Central City during the particle accelerator explosion.*" - https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Jake_Simmons

Comment: By taking meta-vitamins, duh! ;)